# How to catch events about start and finish of task in Camunda?

Tags: camunda

I need to get messages about task started and finished. I'd like to create one common callback and don't modify each task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [camunda-bpm-reactor](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-reactor) extension and the [camunda-spring-boot-starter](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.11/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/the-spring-event-bridge/) (version 3.3 and up) both support registering global listeners for every task "hook" without explicitly adding a listener in the model.
The reactor extension is based on a a meanwhile no longer supported early projectreactor eventbus, so if you are free to choose, I would go for the spring eventing solution.

You can subscribe to all task create events happening in your engine via:

```
@Component
class MyTaskListener {

    @EventListener(condition="#taskDelegate.eventName=='create'")
    public void onTaskEvent(DelegateTask taskDelegate) {
      // do stuff on every task create
    }
}
```